# Total energy oscillations with Runge-Kutta 4th order method - how to avoid them?

Tags: numerical-methods, classical-mechanics, runge-kutta-methods

Consider a free ideal pendulum, which obeys the equations:

$$\frac{d\varphi}{dt}=p \\ \frac{dp}{dt}=-\omega_{0}^{2}\sin\varphi$$

I am applying two 4th order Runge-Kutta schemes: the usual explicit one, and a special implicit scheme I developed.

Both methods are based on the Simpson's formula for a general 1st order ODE:

$$\frac{dy}{dt}=f(y)$$

$$y_{m+1}=y_{m}+\frac{\Delta t}{6}\left[f(y_{m})+4f\left(y_{m+1/2}\right)+f\left(y_{m+1}\right)\right]$$

The difference is in how we estimate $y_{m+1/2}$ and $y_{m+1}$ on the rign hand side.

In the explicit method we proceed with the recurrence:

$$r_1=f(y_{m}) \\ r_2=f\left(y_{m}+\frac{\Delta t}{2}r_1\right) \\ r_3=f\left(y_{m}+\frac{\Delta t}{2}r_2\right) \\ r_4=f\left(y_{m}+\Delta t r_3\right)$$

$$y_{m+1}=y_{m}+\frac{\Delta t}{6}\left[r_1+2r_2+2r_3+r_4\right]$$

In the implicit method I used a special fixed point iteration procedure, which I won't describe here.

---

Calculation parameters are as follows:

$$T=\frac{2\pi}{\omega_{0}}=2,\quad\Delta t=4\cdot10^{-3},\quad\varphi_{0}=5,\quad p_{0}=10$$

The results for the total energy are:

[image]

Where $n=4$ is the number of fixed point iterations I use for the implicit method.

---

While both methods are pretty accurate, there's an energy drift in the explicit method and spurious oscillations in both methods. The oscillations don't seem to be exactly equal to the pendulum period, but close. Maybe because I chose a large angle, the actual period differs from the theoretical value.

**In any case, I would like to know how to modify the method to avoid these oscillations, as they can get quite annoying in more complicated, especially chaotic problems.**

---

**Edit:** Changed the plot so it displays the energy change instead of absolute energy. Also improved the method.

Comment: I don't think you can remove the energy oscillations. For instance, Symplectic Euler preserves the energy function up to $O(\Delta t)$, while other methods preserve energy up to  $O(\Delta t ^2)$ or higher. There will always be oscillations in a band of $O(\Delta t^p)$.

Comment: The problem in this scenario is that you're trying to solve a problem which obeys physical conservation laws. For this kind of problems you may need to use either Newmark/Nystrom method.

Comment: What you observe is the oscillation of the global, accumulated error. As the physical motion is periodic and symmetric, error contributions on the swing left  get repeated with opposite sign on the swing right, so that over a period the error almost cancels. It would give greater insight if you determined the upper and lower values in your plot, as the scale on the left shows a constant. You could also subtract the midpoint value and document it in the axis label. As the error in the energy under RK4 behaves like $t(LΔt)^5$, I would expect the actual with of the band to be of size $10^{-10}$.

Comment: So what you are asking for is an error-free Runge-Kutta method. As of yet, no one has come upon such a thing. // Is your method more advanced than a collocation method for a cubic approximation of the solution?

Comment: @LutzLehmann, thank you for you comments! I edited the question. I also improved the implicit method. The values are not consistent with the error in $\varphi$ of course, because the energy has different dimensions $H = 0.5 p \dot{\varphi} - \omega_0^2 \cos \varphi$, but I understand what you're saying. \\ I haven't tried that cubic collocation method, could you link me to its description?

Comment: In a collocation method you compute, explicitly or implicitly, a polynomial $p$ with $y(t_n+c_ih)\approx p(c_i)$ with the equations $p(0)=y_n$, $p'(c_i)=hk_i=hf(t_n+c_ih,p(c_i))$ and then set $y_{n+1}=p(1)$. So with the 3 nodes $c_1=0$, $c_2=1/2$, $c_3=1$ you get $4$ equations for the $4$ coefficients of a cubic polynomial. Due to the time symmetry of the nodes the generic leading error term has coefficient zero and you get a 4th order method. The Gauss, Radau, .. methods use a special placement of the nodes to get a higher order, only the Gauss methods are symmetric.

Comment: I have implemented this collocation method, the amplitude of the energy oscillations is about twice of what you got, so it is different (RK4 has the same energy errors).

Comment: @LutzLehmann, I use Simpson's 3/8 rule and 2 additional midpoint rules to connect the values at 4 points for each interval and solve a fully implicit system of equations. This requires at least 12 function evaluations for each time step, compared to 4 for explicit Runge-Kutta. How many evaluations does the collocations method require?

Comment: 4 evaluations for an initial RK4 step as predictor. Then 2 evaluations for each corrector step. It seems that here you get the quality of the implicit method with 2 corrector steps (while there is still a noticeable difference to the 3rd corrector step), so that would be 8 evaluations (or 10).

Comment: @LutzLehmann, interesting. By the way, I missed one initial evaluation, so it's 13. One function at $y_m$, then 4 iterations for $y_{m+1/3}, y_{m+2/3}, y_{m+1}$. 4 iterations already give good enough accuracy, though 5 evaluations is needed for several "hard" problems I checked (like double pendulum and Van der Pol oscillator). So it's more like 16 evaluations in the end. Probably better to use regular methods with reduced time step.

Comment: For the more complicated problems (you can uncomplicate Van der Pol using a fast-slow parametrization) you need a variable time step. The optimal step sizes differ more than a factor of 100, so that this extra effort makes for a faster integration without losing quality.

Answer (score 2):

The following is not an answer to the question, as that asks for an error free numerical method, which is impossible.

In the discussion it has been of interest how I would implement the implicit collocation method of order 4 based on the same points as RK4. This turned out to be relatively short,

```
from numba import jit

@jit()
def rk4_step(f,t,y,h):
    k1=f(t,y)
    k2=f(t+h/2,y+h*k1/2)
    k3=f(t+h/2,y+h*k2/2)
    k2=(k2+k3)/2
    k3=f(t+h,y+h*k3)
    return y+h*(k1+4*k2+k3)/6,k1,k2,k3

@jit()
def coll4_step(f,t,y,h,ncorr):
    y3,k1,k2,k3 = rk4_step(f,t,y,h)
    for it in range(ncorr):
        y2 = y+h*(5*k1+8*k2-k3)/24
        k2 = f(t+h/2,y2)
        k3 = f(t+h,y3)
        y3 = y+h*(k1+4*k2+k3)/6
    return y3

@jit()
def odeint4(f,t,y0,ncorr):
    y = np.empty((len(t),)+y0.shape)
    y[0] = y0
    for k in range(1,len(t)):
        h=t[k]-t[k-1]
        y[k] = coll4_step(f,t[k-1],y[k-1],h,ncorr)
    return y
```

The explicit predictor method is standard RK4, so calling with `ncorr=0` corrector steps gives the RK4 base case. The implicit method is the collocation method for the nodes $c_i=0,\frac12,1$. It proceeds by constructing a cubic polynomial $p(s)\approx y(t_n+sh)$ and satisfying $p'(c_i)=hk_i$ where
$$
k_i=y'(t_n+c_ih)=f(t_n+c_ih,p(c_i))$.
$$
This gives via interpolation
$$
p'(s)=h(k_1(s-1)(2s-1)-4k_2s(s-1)+k_3s(2s-1))
$$
The polynomial can now be reconstructed via integration, which concludes the corrector step
$$
p(s)=y_n+\frac{h}{6}(k_1(4s^3-9s^2+6s)-4k_2(2s^3-3s^2)+k_3(4s^3-3s^2)
$$
The only values we need from that polynomial are the point in the middle
$$
p(\tfrac12)=y_n+\frac{h}{24}(5 k_1+8k_2-k_3).
$$
and the next point in the numerical trajectory
$$
y_{n+1}=p(1)=y_n+\frac{h}{6}(k_1+4k_2+k_3),
$$
which is the Simpson rule as expected.

Called with the task parameters

```
from numpy import sin, cos, pi

w0 = pi
u0 = np.array([5.,10.])
t = np.arange(0,20,4e-3)

@jit()
def sys(t,u): y,v = u; return np.array([v,-w0**2*sin(y)])

@jit()
def energy(u): y,v = u; return v**2/2+w0**2*(1-cos(y))

E0 = energy(u0)

%matplotlib inline
plt.figure(figsize=(8,5))
for k in range(4):
    print(f"num corrections = {k}", end="\r")
    u = odeint4(sys,t,u0,k)
    dE = energy(u.T)-E0
    plt.plot(t,dE,label=f"ncorr={k}")
    
plt.grid(); plt.legend(); plt.show()
```

results in the plot of the energy oscillations

[image]

As the 3/8 method in general has half the error of the Simpson method, this is repeated in the implicit methods based on them, as is readily visible.

To get the same reduced error with the Simpson scheme, one would need to divide the step size by $\sqrt[4]2=1.1892$, which increases the number of function evaluations by the same factor. This indicates that the graphs of error vs. function evaluations would look similar for both methods.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Just to clarify the misunderstanding: I was not asking for an error-free method, I was asking for an energy-conserving method, which I believe is possible. Though now I understand that energy conservation doesn't insure physical correctness anyway

Comment: Also, I would try the variable time step approach, but I want to do real time simulation, which could lead to lag if the time step gets too short

Comment: You need to advance to a next stage in your understanding. If the time step in a variable step method gets too short, the reason usually is that you are at a difficult point of the ODE. Also in a fixed-step method you would need to use such a small time step, only that it implies the same short value for the whole integration interval. The usual answer is to use advance-and-interpolate strategies. That means you decouple internal method steps and the output values. The integrator advances to the next output time, using several internal steps if necessary, and interpolates to the output time.

Comment: Thank you, I'll read up on that. Numerical methods are fascinating